# TFS dashboard similar to JIRA

Tags: tfs, dashboard, tfs-2015

I am looking for a way to organise work with our TFS 2015 server.
The main goal I would like to achieve is to have a number of reports (almost like Jira does), which could inform me about:

- Overall user capacity in different project.
- Work done
- Work in progress (pretty sure already exist in TFS)
- Standard reports for management, like hours spent on features, etc.

Additional, but not last at meaning feature I am seeking for is to have user friendly dashboard, like Jira has, with easy way to track work.

I am looking at [Scrum Dashboard](https://scrumdashboard.codeplex.com/), but maybe there are already existing plugins for TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve what you want:

1. TFS 2015 has already integrated [reporting and dashboard features](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview).
2. Integrate SharePoint site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380719.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
3. Integrate reporting service: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/add-a-report-server